# How to override unlink method of one2many field in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I want to override unlink method of one2many field 'order_line' from sale order. I want to restrict the user from deleting record from 'order_line' once added.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by rights management in OpenERP.

Just go to Settings -> Technical -> Security -> Access Control Lists and search for "sale.order.line" or "Sales Order Line". Now change the Access Rules or create new ones. I think the columns speak for themself. If not, just ask me or the other guys here on stackoverflow :-)

If you don't see the Technical Entry in Settings, give your Administrator User/Account the rights to see them. Settings -> Users -> Users -> Administrator -> Tab "Access Rights" -> activate "Technical Features"

Comment: It is indeed a best option to restrict user to delete record.